# ConvertTimeFromUTC, Handling Australia DST

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have the following code, and I have a a customer in Canberra, Australia. They are typically UTC+10, however they are in DST right now so it is UTC+11. What is odd is when I run this code it is not accounting for DST, which I thought ConvertTimeFromUTC handles.

I am passing `E. Australia Standard Time` as the "timeZone" parameter. Any thoughts?

```
var myTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
var currentDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, myTimeZone);
return currentDateTime;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `"AUS Eastern Standard Time"` for South-East Australia (New South Wales and Victoria) that uses DST, including Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney, etc.

Use `"E. Australia Standard Time"` for North-East Australia (Queensland) that does *not* have DST, including Brisbane, Lindeman, etc.

Otherwise, your code is correct.

Note that despite having the word "Standard" in the time zone IDs, .NET and Windows will correctly account for DST where applicable.  There are no IDs that have the word "Daylight" in them.

For a complete list of time zones, use `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` and examine the `.Id` and `.DisplayName` properties of each.  Alternatively, call `tzutil.exe /l` on the command line which will do the same.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have edited my post in regards to the UtcNow. Great tip for the command line access to the list as well!